# How do I pass a list variable from one class's method to a different class's method?

Tags: python

I need to pass selectedCourses from my getSelectedCourses method in the Student class to the Advisor class method ApproveSelectedCourse. I actually need to use the sendCourseRegistrationRequest method from the Student class to pass the selectedCourses list from the getSelectedCourses method to Advisor class method ApproveSelectedCourse but I can't figure out how to pass the list from one class to another. Or how to even pass it to a separate method in the Student class. I'm out of ideas at this point and out of time too. So this is my last shot here. Thanks for any help!

I've tried adding the Student class as an argument to the Advisor class, I've tried defining a variable outside of all the classes to reference the method from the Student class I'm trying to use. I've tried passing the list variable to a separate method in the Student class. I've tried making the Student method a class method and a static method but I'm not even sure how @classmethod & @staticmethod work exactly or how to use them to help me. At this point I've tried everything I can think of.

```
import random

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        print('Student name is: {}'.format(self.name))

class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, stuID):
        #print('I am a student')
        Person.__init__(self, name)
        self.stuID = stuID
        self.finishedCourses = []
        self.selectedCourses = []

    def getStuID(self):
        print('Student ID is: {}'.format(self.stuID))

    def getSelectedCourse(self, courseList):
        SelectedCourse = []
        for i in courseList:
            if i < 400:
                SelectedCourse.append(i)
        #print(SelectedCourse)

        for key in prerequisiteDict.keys():
            if key in SelectedCourse:

                SelectedCourse.remove(key)
        #print(SelectedCourse)

        i = 0

        while i <= 2:

            finishedCourses = random.choice(SelectedCourse)
            self.finishedCourses.append(finishedCourses)
            #print(finishedCourses)

            i += 1

        print('Finished courses: {}'.format(self.finishedCourses))


        x = 0

        while x <= 2:

            selectedCourses = random.choice(courseList)
            self.selectedCourses.append(selectedCourses)

            x += 1

        print('Selected courses: {}'.format(self.selectedCourses))



    def sendCourseRegistrationRequest(self):
        pass
##        for key in prerequisiteDict.keys():
##            if key not in self.finishedCourses:
##
##                self.finishedCourses.remove(key)
##        print('Update selected courses: {}'.format(self.finishedCourses))

    def updateSelectedCourse():
        pass

class Advisor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("I'm here.")
        Person.__init__(self, name)




    def approveSelectedCourse(self, Student):
        print("I'm here2.")
##        Student.__init__(self, finishedCourses)
##        self.var1 = Student.finishedCourses
##        print('self.var1 is {}: '.format(self.var1))
##        
##
##        for key in prerequisiteDict.keys():
##            
##            if key in SelectedCourse:
##                return True
##            else:
##                    self.var1.remove(key)
##                    print('updated course selection: {}'.format(self.selfvar1))
##                    
##                

##        for key in prerequisiteDict.keys():
##            if key in getSelectedCourse:
##
##                getSelectedCourse.remove(key)
##        print(getSelectedCourse)

courseList =  [110, 213, 315, 316, 412, 121, 223, 326, 328, 422,
               136, 238, 335, 336, 432, 140, 243, 345, 346, 448,
               150, 253, 355, 356, 452]

prerequisiteDict = {213:110, 412:316, 326:223, 422:328,
                    238:136, 345:243, 355:253, 452:356}

getSelectedCourse = Student.getSelectedCourse

stuObj = Student('Alice', 98980)
stuObj.getName()
stuObj.getStuID()
stuObj.getSelectedCourse(courseList)
#stuObj.sendCourseRegistrationRequest()
##AdvObj = Advisor('Cindy')
##AdvObj.approveSelectedCourse('Alice')
```

Basically my code works through the Student getSelectedCourses method the way I'm imagining it should. In my mind the easiest way to tackle my problem is to send the self.selectedCourses = [] to the sendCourseRegistrationRequest Student method which will then pass it to the Advisor method approveSelectedCourse which will then check the selectedCourses list and if one of the keys from the prereq is present in selectedCourses it will remove that course from the selectedCourses list. Ideally I just would like to figure out a way to pass the selectedCourses list from the Student class to the Advisor class but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Don't use `Student` as a variable name, it's already the name of a class.

Comment: From within a method, you can run another method with `self.methodName()` and therefore you could pass any object the same way. `self.methodName(var1)`.  From another class you could move objects similarly by either accessing them from storage in the first class or by calling a method on class2 from class1, assuming you had passed in the class object to know what to call.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is organization. Since `Advisor` inherits from `Person`, there is no `self.selectedCourses` attribute to be had. What I would do is one of two things:

1. Store Student instances as a dict within an `Advisor_instance.advisees` attribute, so you can look-up by name
2. Pass the Student instance to the method itself to be able to look up that attribute

## 1

```py
class Advisor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, advisee=None):
        print("I'm here.")
        Person.__init__(self, name)
        self.advisees = {advisee.name: advisee} if advisee else {}

    def add_advisee(self, student_inst):
        if student_inst.name in self.advisees:
            raise KeyError("Entry already exists")
        self.advisees[student_inst.name] = student_inst

    # Easy name lookup and returns the list
    def get_course_list(self, name):
        # Will raise keyerror if name not in advisees
        return self.advisees.[name].selectedCourses    

alice = Student("Alice", 98980)
cindy = Advisor("Cindy", alice)

cindy.get_course_list('alice')
```

Personally, I think this first implementation is a bit more intuitive for your use case. An advisor can have many advisees, and storing the instances of `Student` allows a simple name lookup, you don't need to pass things around.

Extending this more specifically to what you are looking for:

```py
class Advisor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, advisee=None):
        print("I'm here.")
        Person.__init__(self, name)
        self.advisees = {advisee.name: advisee} if advisee else {}

    def add_advisee(self, student_inst):
        if student_inst.name in self.advisees:
            raise KeyError("Entry already exists")
        self.advisees[student_inst.name] = student_inst
    
    def approveSelectedCourse(self, student_name):
        # don't set a self attr here
        # will still raise a KeyError for missing advisees
        var1 = self.advisees[student_name].finishedCourses

        # Do things with var1
```

## 2

```py
class Advisor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("I'm here.")
        Person.__init__(self, name)

    def get_course_list(self, student_inst):
        return student_inst.selectedCourses


alice = Student("Alice", 98980)
cindy = Advisor("Cindy")

cindy.get_course_list(alice)
```

This way would work better if the instance of `Advisor` was more general, i.e. there doesn't need to be a *specific* `Advisor`, only that they are able to accomplish `Advisor`-like methods. In that case, the `name` attribute could drop and the methods could be static, in which case, why have the class?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to pass the Student class as the argument or parameter to the Advisor class instead of passing the Person class so that the Advisor class would inherit the methods from the Student class but our professor stated in the assignment document that all other classes have to inherit from the Person class. I don't know, I wish I would've read this webpage an hour ago. I didn't get any emails from stackoverflow so I didn't figure there would be this helpful of an answer! I just turned in what I had pretty much. :((((((((

Comment: initiating separate instances of different students was also something I meant to add. We were actually supposed to initialize seven separate student instances I just ran out of time and forgot. Heh heh

Comment: I'm trying to run the very first snippet of code you posted and I keep getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/elry2/Documents/Ryan's Folder/IT 170/p4.py", line 114, in <module>
    cindy = Advisor('Cindy', Alice)
NameError: name 'Alice' is not defined

Comment: Ran all three snippets of code and got the same error. Sooooooooo how do I define 'Alice'?

Comment: `alice` would be an instance defined like `alice = Student('Alice')`. If you have defined `alice ` and are trying to pass `Alice`, then you will get a `NameError`

Comment: I guess I'm not getting it. I just copied the code you posted and was getting the NameError.

Comment: What is the `NameError` specifically?